# difference between "English group of students" and "students' English Group"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference

A group of students in my college is starting an English group and they are suggesting the following names:
"English department of students"
"English group of students" 
"English association of students"
I just feel these names sound a bit unneutral so I wanted to ask isn't "students' English group" a better alternative and if the answer is yes then why?

Comment: I think "Students' English group" is better, yes.  "English group of students" is ambiguous about whether it is a group of students who *are* English, or are *studying* English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "School of English" and "English school"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37308/difference-between-school-of-english-and-english-school)

Comment: What implies to the name _English Group_? Does _English_ refer to the _English_ subject or the _British_ nationality?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne The British nationality includes English, Welsh, Scottish and Northern Irish people.

Comment: Should I say one of the British nationality? Actually, that's what I meant. :-)

Comment: Ali, is this group a club for students who are interested in the English language and/or culture? _English department_ sounds like an official part of the college. Here in the UK, students' special interest groups are usually called _societies_. How about something like "XYZ College English Society"?